# How to use `options` binding with an array?

Tags: knockout.js

This works fine:

```
<select>
    <!-- ko foreach: new Array(5) -->
    <option data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

But this shows a dropdown list with empty `option`:

```
<select data-bind="options: new Array(5), optionsText: function(item){return item;}"></select>
```

How to obtain the index from the `optionsText` function?

Comment: This has been requested on knockout github page: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1871

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get an index in this way. [The only parameter you can get is the value of the array item.](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/241c26ca82e6e4b3eaee39e3dc0a92f85bc1df0c/src/binding/defaultBindings/options.js)

Therefore, instead of creating an array with N `undefined` items, you should rather create a range array filled with numbers (your indexes). Consider the code below: (Note that it uses ES6 to generate that array.)

```js
ko.applyBindings({})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: [...Array(5).keys()], optionsText: function(item){return item;}"></select>
```

> [...Array(5).keys()] creates an array: [0,1,2,3,4]

**EDIT:**

Actually, after some thinking I came up with another <s>idea</s> *dirty little hack*. What if you keep the `index` variable in a view model and increment it on getting the label:

```js
ko.applyBindings({index: 0})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: new Array(5), optionsText: function(item){return $data.index++;}"></select>
```

You have to make sure to reset the index on re-rendering the select though.

Comment: This works for smaller data set. But I'm having performance issue with larger data set.

Comment: @RayCheng what kind of N are we talking about? Using `select` for so many options is not the best practice. Maybe you should consider using input type range?